# Getting title of span tag

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, web-crawler

I fetch an element using getElementsByClass and I noticed unusual use of span tag. Instead of spanning some text, the text is actually inside the tag characteristics - title.

Here is what I get:

```
<span style="background-image: url(/img/colors/q5.png); background-size: contain;" class="c-d-pl c-d" title="stainless steel"></span>
```

Here is my code:

```
Jsoup.connect("https://www.e-katalog.ru/ek-list.php?search_="+product).get().getElementsByClass("c-d").get(0)
```

Can someone help to fetch the "title" data of the span tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use attr method to get the attributes of tag

Try below code

```
String s = Jsoup.connect("https://www.e-katalog.ru/ek-list.php?search_="+product).get().getElementsByClass("c-d").get(0).attr("title");
```

Comment: Oh, so stupid that I didn't get it myself. Thank you very much!